# Hardening OSX 10.11

Tags: macos, security

I'm following the instruction, on [hardentheworld.org](http://docs.hardentheworld.org/OS/OSX_10.11_El_Capitan/#disable-bonjour) to harden my OS X 10.11.

When I send the following command:

```
sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder ProgramArguments -array-add "-NoMulticastAdvertisements"
```

I obtain:

```
Could not write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder; exiting
```

My question is why this error happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) (SIP.) It locks up a variety of files to prevent malicious software from modifying it including /System. [You can temporarily disable SIP](http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html), modify your files, then turn it back on if you want to have the maximum protection.